# Transpose of the product of a transpose matrix and itself

Tags: matrices, transpose

We know that

$(AB)^T=B^TA^T$.

Thus:

$(A^TA)^T=(A)^T(A^T)^T=A^TA$.

Is this correct?  I never realize this could be true.  Is there a name to this property?

Comment: True, this means $A^TA$ is a symmetric matrix. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Any matrix $B$ that satisfies $B^T=B$, is called a symmetric matrix.
In fact, given a matrix $A$, the matrix $B=A^TA$ is always symmetric, as you have shown. That is a standard procedure to obtain symmetric matrices.